# In Need of Assistance setting up coding for 4 servos, and 2 joysticks, and where do I connect the SEL connection of the joystick

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

Tony here, and I am a totally new person to the whole arduino world.

First my project, my equipment, why I decided to use arduino, what I am attempting to do, and the code I am using.

My project is relatively simple; the ability to pan and tilt 2 cameras that weight .06 ounce.  The cameras are being used to record the weather.  The programming below works, but the problem I am having is that the servos return to the zero (or do we call it the 90° location) when I release the joystick.  The joysticks I am using are the same type used in the Playstation 2 game pads.  They allow for a Z axis which for me, I would like to use as a way to keep a camera pointed in the direction I last positioned it to, until the time I wish to pan or tilt it to a different axis.  I hope I explained it clearly.

Lastly I do not want to use wireless, I wish to have it hard wired as I believe it will cause less interference by other radio frequencies in my area.

My equipment or components are as follows:

```
 Arduino UNO board

 Bread board

 Circuit board

 2 Joysticks (Playstation 2 style with X, Y and Z axis)

 4 TowerPro servo motors SG5010
```

I decided to use arduino, because it was recommended to me by computer / electronic shop personnel.  I have no prior knowledge of coding arduino or any other type of programming.  I was however able to take coding for 1 joystick and 2 servos, and expand it to include an additional joystick and 2 additional servos.  So as stated, I have coding for 4 servos and 2 joysticks, I just cannot and do not understand what I need to do in order to get the Z axis enabled to do what I stated above.

I apologize to those that are more experienced, that I bring this here, but I really am in need of assistance.

The coding:

```
#include <Servo.h>

const int servo1 = 3;        // first servo
const int servo2 = 11;      // second servo
const int servo3 = 6;        // third servo
const int servo4 = 10;     // fourth servo
const int joyH = 3;           // L/R Parallax Thumbstick
const int joyV = 4;           // U/D Parallax Thumbstick
const int joyI = 1;             // L/R Parallax Thumbstick
const int joyW = 2;          // U/D Parallax Thumbstick
int servoVal;           // variable to read the value from the analog pin

Servo myservo1;  // create servo object to control a servo
Servo myservo2;  // create servo object to control a servo
Servo myservo3;  // create servo object to control a servo
Servo myservo4;  // create servo object to control a servo

void setup() {
    // Servo  
    myservo1.attach(servo1);  // attaches the servo
    myservo2.attach(servo2);  // attaches the servo
    myservo3.attach(servo3);  // attaches the servo
    myservo4.attach(servo4);  // attaches the servo

    // Inizialize Serial
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
    // Display Joystick values using the serial monitor
    outputJoystick();

    // Read the horizontal joystick value  (value between 0 and 1023)
    servoVal = analogRead(joyH);

    servoVal = map(servoVal, 0, 1023, 0, 179);  // scale it to use it with the servo (result  between 0 and 179 to keep from being jittery)

    myservo2.write(servoVal);                  // sets the servo position according to the scaled value    

    // Read the horizontal joystick value  (value between 0 and 1023)
    servoVal = analogRead(joyV);           
    servoVal = map(servoVal, 0, 1023, 0, 179);      // scale it to use it with the servo (result  between 0 and 179 to keep from being jittery)
    myservo4.write(servoVal);                           // sets the servo position according to the scaled value

    // Read the horizontal joystick value  (value between 0 and 1023)
    servoVal = analogRead(joyI);           
    servoVal = map(servoVal, 0, 1023, 0, 179);      // scale it to use it with the servo (result  between 0 and 179 to keep from being jittery)
    myservo1.write(servoVal);                           // sets the servo position according to the scaled value

    // Read the horizontal joystick value  (value between 0 and 1023)
    servoVal = analogRead(joyW);           
    servoVal = map(servoVal, 0, 1023, 0, 179);      // scale it to use it with the servo (result  between 0 and 179 to keep from being jittery)

    myservo3.write(servoVal);                           // sets the servo position according to the scaled value

    delay(15);                                       // waits for the servo to get there
}

/**
 * Display joystick values
 */

void outputJoystick(){
    Serial.print(analogRead(joyH));
    Serial.print ("---"); 
    Serial.print(analogRead(joyV));
    Serial.println ("----------------");
    Serial.print(analogRead(joyI));
    Serial.print ("---"); 
    Serial.print(analogRead(joyW));
    Serial.println ("----------------");
}
```

Thanks for taking the time to help me.  I do appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, I am not real familiar with the Arduino, but.. If you want the camera to NOT move when the joysticks are at neutral position, then you need to add some logic to your loop. You could wrap everything inside your LOOP in an IF statement - if(joystick is NOT at neutral) then {run your code}. This is a quick dirty solution, probably not the preferred method, but it should work. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like the easiest solution is to modify the servos to be continuos rotation (remove the internal servo pot). This will make the servo act the way you want if i'm understanding you right?

You want to move the joystick a little bit and the cameras will start tracking in that direction slowly, and then when you move the joystick more in that direction the camera tracks even faster, and then when you let the joystick to return to the middle, you want the cameras to stop where they are yeah?

If so, we're talking continuos servo rotation behaviour.. This can be simulated using a small device that plugs between the servo and the servo signal. I'd actually love to find the code to make my own version..

Sorry I can't be any more help than that

Cheers

Andy